# Can I submit my manuscript to publisher as well as literary ageant?

Tags: publishing

I was looking for a similar question on this site but did not find one. Can I submit my manuscript to the publisher as well as the literary agent?

Comment: Sure. And multiple of each, if you want to. It's probably worth doing your research (both to know which publishers and agents are trustworthy, and which might be a good match for you and your book).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking about a novel, as along as you are complying with the publisher’s and agent’s submission policies you are free to submit your work to as many people as you want.

The big publishing houses largely don’t accept direct submissions from authors any longer. They rely on agents to filter manuscripts, since the agents know what kinds of pieces the different publishers are interested in.

There are smaller independent publishers that solicit manuscripts from authors.  Some are small presses that operate like a traditional publisher, some are hybrid publishers — something between self-publishing and traditional model that involves cost sharing to lower risks to the imprint, and self-publishing firms — they assist authors through the steps to self-publish their work in exchange for an up front fee or an contract to buy some number of hardcopies.

These last two also contain scammers and vanity presses that will demand money for editing, marketing, and account management services at inflated rates, which are actually part of a publishers costs of doing business.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, publishers tend to fall into two categories: Large publishers will only consider agented submissions. Smaller publishers will consider unagented submissions and agents will generally not submit manuscripts there as the potential revenue from the submission make it not worth their efforts to submit. Furthermore, many smaller presses may operate on a contest model for submissions (this is almost universally the case for poetry publishers) where there is an entry fee to submit¹ which makes it even less likely that publication will lead to a viable return.²

Small presses generally have a more specialized kind of catalog (often leaning more towards the experimental and/or transgressive in their acquisitions) and often are publishing things that the large publishers wouldn't consider (and vice versa). So while you can submit to both publishers and agents, odds are pretty good that you're wasting your time in one category or the other.

---

1. I would recommend *never* paying any sort of entry fee, reading fee or submission fee (that includes the ubiquitous $3 submittable fee). Yes, this ends up meaning that some respected venues are closed off from submissions, but the practice is ripe for abuse. In the 1980s literary agents often charged reading fees and the abuse became so bad that the AALA had to ban the practice. We are likely heading in that direction for submissions to literary journals.
2. A few thousand dollars (which is at the high end of what most small presses would pay and the vast majority would pay $1000 or less) might seem a barely adequate return to the author, but 15% of that small amount doesn't really pay off for an agent who's looking at a payout of a few hundred dollars for what would be at least a week's work.